# Location redirect - is tracking possible?

Tags: php, javascript

I was wondering if someone can help me, I have the following script that redirect users to an affiliate link when they click on a banner.

```
<?php
$targets = array(
'site1' => 'http://www.site1.com/',
'site2' => 'http://www.site2.com/',
'site3' => 'http://www.site3.com/',
'site4' => 'http://www.site4.com/', );
if (isset($targets[$_GET['id']])) {
header('Location: '.$targets[$_GET['id']]);
exit; } 
 ?>
```

Is it possible to track when a user hits the banner telling me the referer site as well as the ip address of the person clicking on the banner.

> hmmmm something like pixel tracking?

I have tried to add an `iframe` that does the tracking but it creates an error

Hope it makes sense

Thanks!

This is more or less how I would have done it in asp

```
   <%

    var Command1 = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command");
    Command1.ActiveConnection = MM_cs_stats_STRING;
    Command1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO stats.g_stats (g_stats_ip, g_stats_referer)  VALUES (?, ? ) ";
    Command1.Parameters.Append(Command1.CreateParameter("varg_stats_ip", 200, 1, 20, (String(Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")) != "undefined" && String(Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")) != "") ? String(Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")) : String(Command1__varg_stats_ip)));
    Command1.Parameters.Append(Command1.CreateParameter("varg_stats_referer", 200, 1, 255, (String(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")) != "undefined" && String(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")) != "") ? String(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")) : String(Command1__varg_stats_referer)));
    Command1.CommandType = 1;
    Command1.CommandTimeout = 0;
    Command1.Prepared = true;
    Command1.Execute();

    %>
```

I am not sure how to do it in php - unfortunately for me the hosting is only supporting php

so I am more or less clueless on how to do it in php

I was thinking if I can somehow call a picture I can do it with pixel tracking in anoter asp page, on another server.

Hope this makes better sense

Comment: I'm sorry, your question is a bit unclear. Can you clarify what you mean? *(And why did you mark up the "hmmmm" comment as code?)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to track ip and referrer using PHP, then use SimpleCoder's advice.

If you want to track ip and referer using some 3rd party javascript tracking code (like Google Analytics or whatever), you can create a "landing" page with a "Refresh" header. Something like

```
...
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=<?php echo $targets[$_GET['id']]?>" />
</head>
...
<script src="some-tracking-code.js"></script>
...
```

Browser will first load this page, javascripts will execute, and then it will redirect to url specified in the header

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=redirect1.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']?>" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.hidden {
 visibility: hidden;
}
-->
</style>
<iframe src="http://www.domain.com/tracker.asp" class="hidden"></iframe>

Comment: Thanks German - I think I have solved it but don't think it is the most elegant way of doing it - on the redirect.asp I have the code writing the hit to the DB via an .asp page, and then the meta refresh redirects to redirect1.php and does the actual redirecting to the site the user clicked on - Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

These should help:

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

and

```
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

**Just as a heads up:** the referrer can be spoofed.

To actually track these and record them you will need to use a database. I would recommend MySQL. But, this is a whole other matter entirely.

Comment: Thanks SimpleCoder - I am using these I am just not sure how to implement it - I am also not sure if it is possible to do it within the script.

Comment: If I understand well, he wants to know when a user click on a banner on *his* site.  The Referer header will only be useful from the *affiliated sites*.

Comment: I don't think there is too much of a difference either way. When this script executes, it can still capture the referrer and IP address, just as it would on an affiliate site.

Comment: Ok, all you need to do is connect to the DB and execute a query to add a row. I recommend using a database abstraction layer, like PDO, to makes things easier. Check out EasyPDO: http://easypdo.robpoyntz.com/

Comment: Thanks SimpleCoder appreciate your advice and tips. I have done it with 2 redirects and it seems to work, although I don't think it is the most ellegant way - your help however is much appreciated!